# Xamarin UWP Listview ViewCell with images memory issue

Tags: image, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am working on UWP version of a Xamarin App and the ViewCell that I am working with in a Listview shows images just fine, but there it stops running after I scroll about half way through the list. If I use an ImageCell it works just fine but the images are not the right size. Anyone have any ideas? Also I am using FFImageloading in my project and this isn't helping with UWP. I have tried to implement a custom viewCell renderer similar to [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/ViewCell)  but nothing shows

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your image size and make it smaller, in android you will have problems because somehow there is no garbage collection.. I had the same issue..